# the sound within <audio> is not recognized

Tags: html, html5-audio, filepath

I am following a w3school [audio tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_audio)

The issue is that the audio file is not found. When I click on the link where the browser is looking for the audio it is showing:

```
file:///D:/________mySite/sounds/Silence.mp3
```

Which is indeed the place where the .mp3 is.

Any ideas how to resolve this?

The code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Kawasaki - ultimate superbikes</title>
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<link href="default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
<!-- start header -->
<audio controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop">
  <source src="sounds/Silence.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="sounds/Silence.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
 Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try putting the sound inside the same folder as your webpage, and simply using `src="Silence.mp3"` - chances are the path isn't working

Comment: Tried this too... did not help. Page is html without js at the moment.

Comment: Please link your complete code

Comment: have you tried src="./sounds/Silence.mp3"

Comment: or if that fails "../sounds/Silence.mp3"

Comment: Really appreciate the suggestion of adding ./ and ../ but fortunately it did not work.

Comment: @Dominating if the HTML File is in **mySite**, you should use `src="./sounds/Silence.mp3"`. Try to refresh your browser (in Firefox **CTRL+F5**)

Comment: What browser are you using (including version number)? Because it shouldn't be displaying "Your browser does not support the audio element" if your browser did.

Instead you would just see disabled audio controls.

Comment: I could be wrong, but it looks like you're trying to access a local file, you need to have your audio files on a server to load them in the browser.